# filter by last digit works in points but not in lines

Tags: pyqgis, filter, qgis-python-console, hub-lines

I have three-point layers T, A1 and A2. T is original points and A1 and A2 are generated by some algorithms. I am trying to compare the result of A1 and A2 with T.

On T, A1 and A2 I can apply a filter at one from a console with this code.

```
layers = iface.mapCanvas().layers()
for layer in layers:
    layer.setSubsetString('"field_3" % 100 = 1')
```

After that, I create hub lines T-A1 and T-A2. I want to filter these lines too same as the points, but the filters don't work. I also tried with strings

```
right("field_3",1) LIKE '1'
```

in the layer filter but it shows all the lines without filtering.

NOTE: this expression `right("field_3",1)` works in the label expression

Comment: What is the field type of `field_3` in your hub line layers? Could you create a new integer field using one of the expressions you mentioned and then use this field in the query?

Comment: they are strings in all the layers. I have tried to convert to int in the expression `'int(right("field_3",1)) % 100 = 1'`. it also didn't work.